# Nested json objects in logstash aggregate filter plugin

Tags: json, ruby, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-jdbc

I'm using logstash aggregate filter plugin to insert data to ES.

I want to create a json like

```
"Countries" : {
        "Asia" : {
            "name" : "Srilanka"
        },
        "Africa" : {
            "name" : "Kenya"
        }
    }
```

when uploaded to ES.

I have tried

```
map['Countries'] = {
        map['Asia'] =  {
            'name' => event.get('name_Asia')
        },
        map['Africa'] =  {
            'name' => event.get('name_Africa')
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Is it possible to make create above json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place to produce nested hashes, you should use hashrockets `=>` not assignments inside a hash. One might create this hash in one turn:

```rb
map = { 
  'Countries' => {
    'Asia' =>  {
      'name' => event.get('name_Asia')
    },
    'Africa' => {
      'name' => event.get('name_Africa')
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can produce JSON out of it with [`JSON.dump`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-dump)

```rb
require 'json'
JSON.dump(map)
```